# How 'bout a quick review of our MTG tags?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

We have a lot of MTG questions, so categorizing them is probably important. I was looking at our MTG tags today. Currently, it looks like we have:

General:

- `magic-the-gathering`
- `mtg` -> synonym for `magic-the-gathering`

Formats:

- `mtg-modern`
- `mtg-commander`
- `mtg-cube`
- `mtg-pauper`
- `mtg-planechase`
- `mtg-drafting`

Other:

- `mtg-history`
- `mtg-manabase`

Prominent overlapping generic tags:

- `rules`
- `strategy`
- `deck-building`
- `multi-player`
- `sealed-deck` -- so far this is only attached to MTG Sealed questions

Do any of these call out for synonyms, name changes, &c.? Are there obvious categories we are missing, representing unlabeled or underrepresented content?

Comment: Gah.  For the love of god, quit flooding the front page with re-tags!  Can we assume that a question is a rules question by Default?

Comment: @CaulynDarr That's me. Sorry, I didn't knew that just retag would do this. Still, It would be good to retag them, so searchs are improved. I'll stop now, anyway.

Comment: @Pablo Improving tags is fine, but you pushed every other game question from the last week waaaaaaay off the font page.

Comment: @Pablo I remember reading somewhere that just retagging without any body-text doesn't actually bump the question... I guess that is untrue! :(

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion:

1. Limited tags should probably match official format names:

   - `mtg-drafting` => `mtg-draft`
   - `sealed-deck` => `mtg-sealed` (my assumption is that this tag is actually game-specific; I don't know of non-MTG sealed, and it probably doesn't *play* like MTG Sealed)
2. `mtg-history` seems like it should be a generic tag instead (like `strategy` and `rules` are). Seems to fit other game questions like, "What are the differences between the first-edition and current rules of Carcassone?"

Comment: There is draft and sealed in other games, at least in [L5R](http://rules.l5r.com/Sealed_Deck) and probably more games. Should these be generic tags or specific to magic?

Answer (score 1):

I also found the tag `two-headed-giant`, that should be `mtg-two-headed-giant`.

`innistrad` should be `mtg-innistrad`.

There are also questions about limited formats, not specific to sealed or draft. Perhpas a `mtg-limited` tag should be created?
Examples:

[Relative amounts of luck in MTG limited formats?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/7265/2474)

[How many lands should I have in my sealed or draft decks?](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/4957/2474)

Comment: Is it reasonable to merge mtg-drafted and mtg-sealed into mtg-limited?

Comment: @Circeus Tricky question! There's a lot of overlap between Sealed and Draft in terms of card evaluation and deck-building, but they play very differently as well. If we're going to distinguish between Standard and Modern, I think it makes sense to distinguish between sealed and draft as well.

Comment: @AlexP Well, right now we have 4 sealed-deck and 21 mtg-drafting (which *include* the 4 sealed-deck, as those four are double-tagged), so the question whether there is a need for the split currently is certainly warranted.

Comment: @Circeus Actually, I was talking about adding the mtg-limited tag in top of the existing ones, not instead of them.